# Can I add insulation to exterior home walls without redoing all the drywall?

Tags: insulation

I recently bought a house and Ive found out the insulation is not good enough in the exterior walls.  Is there a way that I can just cut a small hole and maybe blow in insulation into the walls instead of tearing down all the drywall?

Is this a diy project or should I hire someone?

Comment: Would it be easier to take the siding off the outside instead? Continuous insulation beats cavity insulation, inch for inch, every time....

Comment: you almost assuredly don't want to DIY on this; there can be complicated issues with moisture, mold, off-gassing, blockage, electrical considerations, etc. Not to mention the specialized equipment and bulk-only materials required. Get someone who stands behind the work and pay them. It'tl be a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are companies that will drill 2" holes at two or three places in each stud cavity. You're left to repair the drywall if it's done from the inside. It can also be done from outside, through the wall sheathing, if you're replacing siding. In this case, patches aren't really needed. House wrap covers the holes.

I don't know of anywhere that rents the equipment for that. The insulation medium is often beaded polystyrene, but it could be fiberglass. It's fairly specialized. You'd have to check around your area.

Comment: I did blow in insulation in my attic.  Would it be the same insulation?  Lowes and Home Depot had a rental unit for that. The only issue would be the tube was pretty wide.

Comment: Probably not. It's a special medium that's designed to flow well.

Answer (score 0):

RetroFoam insulation for your existing walls.  Can be done from the outside of the house and you'll never know they were even there.  You can call the main company called Polymaster, in Knoxville, Tennessee to find out where the closest dealer is to you.  My company is a dealer for them and we absolutely love our relationship with them.  It's available throughout the US and other parts of the world.  You can watch the process on most social media platforms.  Has a higher R Value than other types of insulation and has a lifetime guarantee.  We have insulated all of our many rental properties with it when we were training and had great success with lower bills for tenants as well as an energy credit from the government.  It's non invasive as well by not having to rip out walls or fix holes in drywall because it can be done completely from the outside even if you have brick, aluminum, wood, or vinyl on the outside of your home.  And they will seal the areas after the insulation is installed.  Also, it dos not expand like spray foam, but rather fills the void.  Hope this helps.